# PHP included script logic not understood

Tags: php, return, include

File b.php

```
<?php
if(defined('Yes')) return;
define('Yes', 1);
function f(){
     return 0;
}
?>
```

File a.php

```
<?php
    include 'b.php';
    include 'b.php';
?>
```

I expect the above code should not result an error. But, error message says function f is already defined.

But if b.php is modified like

```
<?php
if(!defined('Yes')){
define('Yes',1);
function f(){
     return 0;
}
}?>
```

It works. What is this behaviour to be understood?

Comment: You can only define once. The second include defines again.

Comment: the function was declared within the global scope, no matter if you place it at the top of your code or way bottom, it will be loaded in the stack. Even if there is a breaking of the execution flow (`return;`) "before" the function declaration, the function is still present in the stack

Comment: In the second example, the function is declared within the `if () { }` scope. It will be evaluated only when the scope will be reached

Comment: When included multiple times, why is that first form of  b.php does not work but second form of b.php does work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP "looks ahead" for top-level function and class definitions, so that you can write code like this:

```php
do_stuff();
do_more_stuff();
exit;

function do_stuff() {
    // lots of code here
}
function do_more_stuff() {
    // even more code
}
```

In order to do that, *as soon as the file is compiled*, function declarations are processed, and "forward declared", so that you don't get an "undefined function" error. In this example, the lines where the functions are declared are never even reached, but the declarations are processed at compile time, so it runs fine.

This is what happens in your first code: the function declaration is processed as soon as you include the file, before PHP even looks at the if statement.

However, when you put the whole block inside a condition like this ...

```php
do_stuff();
do_more_stuff();
exit;

if ( true ) {
    function do_stuff() {
        // lots of code here
    }
    function do_more_stuff() {
        // even more code
    }
}
```

... the compiler spots that the declaration is *conditional*, and waits until that code is actually executed, when the run-time can check the condition. Even though the condition above is always true, the code gives an "undefined function" error, because the functions weren't declared yet when we tried to run them.

This is what happens in your second code: PHP waits until the if statement has run, and only declares the function when and if it reaches that line.

---

As an aside, this whole pattern of "if some constant is defined then exit" is very rare in PHP, because you can just use [`include_once`](https://php.net/include_once) or [`require_once`](https://php.net/require_once), and it will handle it all for you.